# Reading cookies across different hosts

Tags: jquery, iframe, cookies

I have two sites - both are my projects. On site two, I need to check if the user is logged in on site one. I suppose to do this I should just create a script that puts a cookie into the body of an iframe and then read the iframe contents on site two. But I can't.

Here is a code I made for testing purposes:
http://jsbin.com/oqaza/edit

I got an error, that says:

> "Permission denied for
>   <http://jsbin.com> to get property
>   HTMLDocument.nodeType from
>   <http://www.google.com>."

Comment: This will never gonna work that way. Just image that an ebay-iframe would hold my cookie data and you were allowed to read this from your controlled site.

Guess you have to do this server-side.

Comment: This works here, on stack overflow, where user can login using google account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. Generally there is solution like "OpenID" (used even here on SO), but I discovered, that JSONP is easiest way to read cookies across domain :)

Comment: how are you accomplishing this?  i see issues with IE, which doesn't send cookies to a different domain when a JSONP request is made.

Answer (score 1):

Iframe documents are subject to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) - you can't access content on one host from a page on another host.  The same is true of AJAX requests.

For modern browsers, one solution is [Cross Document Messaging](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-html-5-postmessage).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, using cookies is not a good option due to security concerns.  You *could* do it by punting a logged in user back to the other site, checking the cookie, and punting them back to the page they were on with a query string indicating status, but this is clunky to say the least.

A better way would be to create a web service (or an MVC JsonResult if you are into .Net MVC) on site1 that can respond to an AJAX request from site2 regarding login status.